# How do I prevent the drop down menu from closing the other fields when it opens?

Tags: swiftui

[image: dropdown]

**But I want the drop down menu to open over the text fields below as in the second photo.
Getting it into Z Stack hasn't been a solution.But I may be writing in the wrong place.**

[image: image 2]

**Dropdown code**

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
        DisclosureGroup("\(selectedScrollNum)", isExpanded: $isScrollExpanded)  {
            ScrollView{
               VStack{
                
                ForEach(1...50,id:\.self){ code in
                    Text("\(code)")
                        .font(Font.custom("Barlow-Regular", size: 12))
                        .padding(.all)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.selectedScrollNum = code
                            withAnimation{
                                self.isScrollExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }//foreach
             }//VSTACK
            }.frame( height:120)
           // .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("dg1"),Color("dg2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
           // .background(Color("dg2"))
            .background(Color.blue)     
          }//Disclosure
        .accentColor(.black)
        .font(Font.custom("Barlow-Regular", size: 17))
        .padding()
       
        
     Spacer()
           
        }.frame(height:180)
       
        
    }
```

**Login Page Then I put the dropdown menu I created on the login screen.**

```
  VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3){
            
             HStack{
               
                //CODE
                   
                    VStack{
                   
                        Divider()
                         .padding(.top,30)
                          .padding(.leading,-6)
                    } .frame(width: 100)
                   .padding(.leading)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack{
                            CountryCodeDropdown()
                        }.padding(.top, 110)
                    
                    )

                //PHONE
                CustomTextField(title: "Phone", value: $model.phone, animation: animation)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }//:HSTACK
```

Comment: If this app is for iOS, then you should not be using a drop-down. Apple may reject your app if it doesn't have a simple UI that makes sense. Instead, you should be using a SwiftUI Picker to accomplish the same function.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Someone would have to do a fair amount of work to turn the code you included into something compilable